# Set variable to result of executed statement in a sproc

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, dynamic-sql

Do you have any good concise tutorials about variable syntax? This is part of a sproc:

```
Set @sql = 'Set ' + @calc + '= SUM(datalength(' + @column_name + '))/2 from ' + @table_name 
exec (@sql)
```

And it doesn't work - I get an `Error converting data type varchar to numeric.` Here is the simulated example:

```
DECLARE @calc numeric(18,2)
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(1500), @column_name nvarchar(50), @table_name nvarchar(50)
Set @column_name = 'EID'
Set @table_name = 'CTY_SUPPORTED'
Set @sql = 'Select @calc = SUM(datalength(' + @column_name + '))/2 from ' + @table_name
exec (@sql)
print @calc
```

I'm interested in attributing to variable @calc the following value: `SUM(datalength(column_x))/2 from table_x`

Also if you know syntax lessons (preferably not encyclopedias) - many thanks and gooday!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Set @sql = 'Select @calc = SUM(datalength(' + @column_name + '))/2 from ' + @table_name 
exec (@sql)
```

Comment: Thank you but it says: `Incorrect syntax near 'EID'` and `Must declare the scalar variable "@calc".` (you can see my edited question)

Comment: Isn't that a dead giveaway that you `Must declare the scalar variable "@calc".`?

Comment: Not sure what you mean, I am declaring that in the first line: DECLARE @calc numeric(18,2)

Comment: Ah my mistake, you need to execute the dynamic sql with [`sp_executesql`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms188001.aspx) to include parameters.

Comment: Thanks flem, very useful to know about the sp_executesql!